# Is clang-tidy backward compatible?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

Let's assume we compose .clang-tidy yaml file on version X of clang-tidy. Should we synchronize this X version across all team members and CI? If someone update his clang-tidy version to more abvanced, will he get different diagnostics with the same config file?

It will be convenient to not bind to particular clang-tidy version especially if it supplied with IDE and updated automatically with IDE update

Comment: "If someone update his clang-tidy version to more abvanced, will he get different diagnostics with the same config file?" - Newer clang-tidy versions may give more diagnostics for the same options.

Comment: In principle synchronising tech stack depends on what you make. If it is specific product for concrete platform then sync heavily and strictly ... if it is portable product for variety of platforms go as loose and different as possible. But clang-tidy is tool that does nothing, only whines ... so it does not matter.

Comment: @ÖöTiib with proper configuration it can fix up code (just nitpicking).

Comment: @MarekR Yes. Mea culpa. I mean't that if integrated into automated toolchain then it should be only set to whine. It can refactor code but those features should be used in code editing phase.